# fade a gallery of 9 thumbnails in randomly 1 at a time using jquery without hover

Tags: jquery, gallery, thumbnails, image-gallery

This example

http://jsfiddle.net/wCb93/1/

...appears to be what I need except my images are 137x109 (9 images). They need to fade in and out randomly continually without hover or mouse activation. The 3 x 3 setup is ideal for me so I think it just need a few tweaks. I have only ever worked in flash so this is completely new to me... so please be gentle!

The site is

http://www.incyteventures.com/index.html

As you can see not ideal... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards
Les

Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save this code as a *.js file (i modified it a little):

```
$(function(){
    changeImg();
})

function changeImg(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(9));
    var theImage = $('#container > img').eq(randomNumber);

    if (theImage.css("opacity")==0){
        theImage.delay(500).animate({
            opacity:1
        },250, function(){
            changeImg();
        });
    } else {
        theImage.delay(500).animate({
            opacity:0
        },250, function(){
            changeImg();
        });
    }
}
```

your should look something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>fancy_fade_outs</title>
<style type="text/css">
img {
    display: block;
    width: 137px;
    min-height: 109px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    opacity:0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}

#container {
    width: 438px; /* =(image width + margin right)*3  */
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jquery on google-->
<script src="fadeScript.js"></script><!-- path to your script-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/50/000/000" /><div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
​
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the jquery selector ( jQuery() or $() ) you have an object that acts like an array, by using the get() method you can pick an especific object of that collection.
So all you have to do is: capture the images with selector, pick a random number from 0 to the object length, call a fadeToggle (requires jQueryUI). Then you setInterval to that function. Note: the setInterval must take the same or more time than the fadeToggle, otherwise images won't completely fade in our out.

Answer (score 0):

i've forked the jsfiddle and added fadeIns. Is this what you are looking for? 
http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsausage/JBmks/

dont use the build in fades because they set your elements css to

```
display:none
```

at the end of the fadeOut animation

Comment: I think this is going to do the job perfectly! My friend is over tomorrow to insert as I am rubbish at this code. Without me being a complete idiot, is it easy enough to create it to work with 137w x 109h and 9px between so it is 429px wide x 345px high. Would be great  if I have it all ready for her :)

Comment: the dimension of the divs is easy css modification. here it comes: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsausage/gNt68/

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It looks great and I've tweaked it slightly to the correct width and height. I am however having a few other issues. When I try to imbed the result as per the documents, it’s showing the result with all of the tab panes around it. How do I display it without these?

Comment: I have also tried it by adding the css to my css. I’ve created a js file called array.js and copied the js into it. I’ve assigned array.js at the top of the html file. I have then copied the html into my page. It displays the images but without any functionality. How do I assign the js to this particular div? Ideally I need a html file showing just the images with the css and js attached to it. I also notice that in the html is says div=container however nowhere in the css does it specify ‘container’.

So sorry for the questions!! Any help is greatly appreciated!!